# Use jQuery set .css RIGHT if #foo + offset left is greater than page width

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, syntax

Ok, so I am trying to use jQuery to get the `innerWidth()` of an element `#preview`.  I want to create a conditional that says IF x offset LEFT + #preview width is greater than page width, give it style `right: z` where z = #preview width + xOffset.

I apologize my code below is a mess and the syntax for `.css ("right", (rightFloat + xOffset) + "px")` (line 125) is off, but that's part of my problem.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

    //append "gallery" class to all items with "popup" class
    imagePreview();
    $(".popup").addClass("gallery");
});    

//The overlay or pop-up effect
this.imagePreview = function() { /* CONFIG */

    xOffset = 40;
    yOffset = 40;

    // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
    // you might want to adjust to get the right result
    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.preview").click(function(e) {
        return false;
    });
    $("a.preview").hover(function(e) {
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        var rightFloat = e.pageX + ("#preview").innerWidth;
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='" + this.href + "' alt='Image preview' />" + c + "</p>");
        $("#preview").hide().css("top", (e.pageY - yOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + xOffset) + "px").fadeIn("2000");
        while ((left + 400) > window.innerWidth) {.css("right", (rightFloat + xOffset) + "px")
        }
    }, function() {
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#preview").remove();
    });
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e) {
        var top = e.pageY - yOffset;
        var left = e.pageX + xOffset;
        var rightFloat = e.pageX + ("#preview").innerWidth;
        //flips the image if it gets too close to the right side
        while ((left + 400) > window.innerWidth) {.css("right", +(rightFlaot + xOffset) + "px")
        }
        $("#preview").css("top", top + "px").css("left", left + "px");
    });
};


</script>
```

Comment: Basically I screwed up the syntax, I think I'm close but it's failing because of the syntax bug right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using http://api.jquery.com/offset/

```
if($('#preview').offset().right<0){
   var right = parseInt($(window).width()) - e.pageX + xOffset;
   $("#preview").css("top", top + "px").css("right", right + "px");
}else{
   var left = e.pageX + xOffset;
   $("#preview").css("top", top + "px").css("left", left + "px");
}
```

I made these fixes because I couldn't get your code to work in jsfiddle:

<strike>var xOffset = 40;
var yOffset = 40;
$("a.preview").bind('mouseover',function(e){
    var rightFloat = parseFloat(e.pageX)+$("#preview").innerWidth();

    var ptop = parseFloat(e.pageY) - yOffset;
    var pleft = parseFloat(e.pageX) + xOffset;
    $("#preview").css({"top":ptop + "px","left":pleft + "px"});
});</strike>

There's the fixes for the top half but I have no idea what you're trying to do with the bottom part (with the while loop). Can you explain what functionality you want?

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately the `rightFloat` value you created here doesn't have any impact on the function.  The idea is that instead of `position: left` it tests the xPosition of the #preview + `$("preview").innerwidth()` ... if the total > is greater than the total width of the window, (e.g. the photo would appear cut off beyond the pages margin, then it INSTEAD gives it `right: y` where y = #preview.innerWidth + xOffset.

Comment: you can see it working mostly correctly on the development site: http://drm.st/5tst.  This displays the bug if you hover the photos (scroll down the page) on the far left - they appear off screen.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. My first answer probably didn't help much at all then. Revised above.